# Как изменятся координаты, если ось у направить вниз?

Tags: python, математика

Есть координаты точек: (-7; -2), (-3; 4), (-1; 4), (2; 7), (2; 4), (5; 4), (9; -5), (10; -9), (8; -8), (5; -10), (7; -5), (3; -2), (-7; -2)

Должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить координаты, если ось Y направить вниз и получился бы такой же рисунок?

Comment: просто - `y1 = -y0`

Comment: При этом условии отражается симметрично, но не выравнивается

Comment: А что значит "не выравнивается"?

Comment: сама акула не как на данной картинке изображена, а перевернута

Comment: Если нужна перевернутой — не меняйте координаты. Или вы ось развернули, но все равно считаете, что если поменять знаки у `y`, то точка изменится? :)